# passing class member variables to the start routine that is passed into pthread_create

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose you have the following:

***Test.h***

```
class Test {
public:

    Test();
    // Other member variables
    void createThread();

}
```

***Test.cpp***

```
void* threadRunnable(void* arg) {
// Uses Test class member variables
}

Test::Test(){
//
}

void Test::createThread() {

    pthread_create(..,threadRunnable,..);

}
```

How would the function `threadRunnable` passed into `pthread_create` be able to access member variables without instantiating an object? Or is this not possible.

Things I've tried:

- Singleton with a reference to the class (don't think this works as you still need an object first)
- Making the function `threadRunnable` a member or `friend` function

Not sure what else can be done

Comment: Unrelated: Why use the platform specific C library `pthread` instead of the standard C++ `std::thread` or `std::jthread`?

Comment: What Ted said, and use lambda expressions to pass parameters to your thread functions.  For C++20 use [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) for older versions use [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).  And if you have a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) you can pass it in as constructor argument of your thread. If you want a thread to calculate something and return the answer later use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and you can use a lambda expression with a return value

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to supply the pointer to `threadRunnable` to `pthread_create` and also a pointer to `this`. Then cast `arg` to a `Test*`. I'm using `NULL` and a C style cast from `void*` to `Test*` instead of `nullptr` and a `static_cast` which will work in pre C++11:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    ~Test() {
        pthread_join(th, NULL);
    }
    void createThread();

private:
    friend void* threadRunnable(void*);
    pthread_t th;
    int x;
};

void* threadRunnable(void* arg) { // <-----------+
    Test& tst = *((Test*)(arg)); // *this        |
    // Uses Test class member variables //       |
    tst.x = 10; //                               |
    std::cout << tst.x << '\n'; //               |
    return NULL; //                              |
} //                                             |
//                                               |
void Test::createThread() { //                   |
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, &threadRunnable, this);
}

int main() {
    Test tst;    
    tst.createThread();
}
```

---

A somewhat cleaner way that was often used before C++11 was to make `threadRunnable` a member function and to use a `static` proxy function with `phtread_create`:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    ~Test() {
        pthread_join(th, NULL);
    }
    void createThread();

private:
    static void* runnableProxy(void*);
    void threadRunnable();
    pthread_t th;
    int x;
};

void* Test::runnableProxy(void* instance) {
    ((Test*)instance)->threadRunnable();
    return NULL;
}

void Test::threadRunnable() {
    // Uses Test class member variables
    x = 10;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

void Test::createThread() {
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, &Test::runnableProxy, this);
}

int main() {
    Test tst;    
    tst.createThread();
}
```

---

In modern C++ you'd use `std::thread` or `std::jthread` instead and then there's no need for a proxy function:

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Test {
public:
    void createThread();

private:
    void threadRunnable();
    std::jthread th;
    int x;
};

void Test::threadRunnable() {
    // Uses Test class member variables
    x = 10;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

void Test::createThread() {
    th = std::jthread(&Test::threadRunnable, this);
}

int main() {
    Test tst;
    tst.createThread();
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain how the solution with pthread may work?

Comment: @jeff I have two `pthread` based solutions in the answer. The first one looks very similar to your code. Did you manage to get it working? If you did, but don't understand why, please ask about the part you want me to clarify further.